# Error in display image when running opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to read and display an image using opencv library in python. Here's my code:

```
import cv2
path = r'/Users/mihirtalsania/Documents/ptobmk4unp151.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

when I run the code, I get the following error:

> You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
>   QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7fcca7eb6410) is not the object's thread (0x7fccaa4fe6f0).
>   Cannot move to target thread (0x7fcca7eb6410)

Comment: Using Spyder on Anaconda on Mac